# Bug in foreach? Error in task AFTER all tasks have completed/combined?

Tags: r, foreach

I have a foreach, using .combine = rbind and with 112 tasks, 6 parallel operations at a time.  With verbose on, I can see that all tasks complete AND combine, but then I get the message "task 6 failed - "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

So I tried to run just the last 12 tasks and everything worked fine!  So the last 12 don't seem to have any issues and per the verbose output, the first 100 combined successfully.

help! =)

```
numValues: 112, numResults: 0, stopped: TRUE
automatically exporting the following variables from the local environment:
  data, dependentVariables, groupByVariable, numberOfBinsForMissingValueHistogram, outputDirectory 
got results for task 1
numValues: 112, numResults: 1, stopped: TRUE
returning status FALSE
...
got results for task 100
numValues: 112, numResults: 100, stopped: TRUE
first call to combine function
evaluating call object to combine results:
  fun(result.1, result.2, result.3, result.4, result.5, result.7, 
    result.8, result.9, result.10, result.11, result.12, result.13, 
    result.14, result.15, result.16, result.17, result.18, result.19, 
    result.20, result.21, result.22, result.23, result.24, result.25, 
    result.26, result.27, result.28, result.29, result.30, result.31, 
    result.32, result.33, result.34, result.35, result.36, result.37, 
    result.38, result.39, result.40, result.41, result.42, result.43, 
    result.44, result.45, result.46, result.47, result.48, result.49, 
    result.50, result.51, result.52, result.53, result.54, result.55, 
    result.56, result.57, result.59, result.60, result.61, result.62, 
    result.63, result.64, result.65, result.66, result.67, result.68, 
    result.69, result.70, result.71, result.72, result.73, result.74, 
    result.75, result.76, result.77, result.78, result.79, result.80, 
    result.81, result.82, result.83, result.84, result.85, result.86, 
    result.87, result.88, result.89, result.90, result.91, result.92, 
    result.93, result.94, result.95, result.96, result.97, result.98, 
    result.99, result.100)
returning status FALSE
got results for task 101
numValues: 112, numResults: 101, stopped: TRUE
...
got results for task 112
numValues: 112, numResults: 112, stopped: TRUE
calling combine function
evaluating call object to combine results:
  fun(accum, result.101, result.102, result.103, result.104, result.105, 
    result.106, result.107, result.108, result.109, result.110, 
    result.111, result.112)
returning status TRUE
Error in { : task 6 failed - "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"
```

Comment: It would help to know what exactly you're doing... Things like this can happen with random processes, advanced fitting methods that can be dependent on the start parameters, disrupted input objects and so on. A traceback() could help as well. As for the error method, I hope you noticed that result.6 never got included in the combine...

Comment: @Joris - I'm iterating through columns in a dataframe and calculating a bunch of statistics (like %missing, standard deviation, etc.).  This is the first I'm hearing about traceback() so I will dig deeper.  I didn't notice the result.6!  good catch!  I'll have to isolate to that (I falsely assumed foreach would just stop when it encountered an error)

Comment: @Joris - I had an issue with my function that caused task 6 to fail...could you post your comment as an answer so I can accept and give you credit?  Thanks again for catching this, I really needed the second set of eyes.

Comment: Although it doesn't resolve this per se, I have found that it can make debugging a lot less painful to not have the loop abort at an errorr, especially if it takes a long time to complete.  For me, it is useful to include the `.errorhandling` flag, e.g. `foreach(.errorhandling = "pass")`.  I do this if it will take a long time to finish the operation - I'd like to fix the anomaly separately and that may be easier and quicker to fix, so long as a check for errors is built in to post-processing of the results.  Also, as Joris suggests, example code would be very useful.

Comment: @Iterator - its good to know about .errorhandling!  The documentation for "stop" should mention that that option does not immediately terminate upon error.  It would be nice to have an option to stop immediately.  I like to fix bugs at the time they happen and not have to worry about post-processing results.  The bigger issue (IMHO) is not when a foreach stops.  Unless I'm missing an option? it seems that foreach does not capture a stacktrace or any context that can be used to isolate a bug.  I had to run my function serially to pinpoint the line of code that raised the error.

Comment: @SFun28: Play with the error handling a bit, and I think you'll like some of the functionality.  I usually prefer fast failure, but for jobs where the total time to run is considerable and failure is rare, it's less disruptive to redo/fix/ignore the failures than to lose hours of work.

Comment: One other suggestion: if you're doing a lot of stuff, you might generate a different set of keys to describe the jobs, so that you can queue your weakest runs (i.e. most likely to fail) at the beginning or at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would help to know what exactly you're doing... Things like this can happen with random processes, advanced fitting methods that can be dependent on the start parameters, disrupted input objects and so on. A `traceback()` could help as well, although the output of the `traceback()` can be pretty unreadible in the case of parallel tasks. But in essence, something is going wrong with the combination of a specific input and your function.

As for the error, I hope you noticed that result.6 never got included in the combine. So I would first look at what exactly happens in task6, and why it doesn't return any output.

Comment: Along the same lines as `traceback()`, another useful debugging tool is to set `options(error = recover)`. That allows you to browse variables, as seen from within the function that called the error.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question, however, I discovered it after facing similar issues with the `foreach` in R. This may be of help to others.

I can't see the original code, but I found when I reduced the number of cores in `parallel::makeCluster()` from 24 to 16, the error *"task XX failed"* wasn't reproducible. It's been years since I spent time digging away at parallel code, but I'll fathom a guess that a node was either assigned nothing to do or had nothing to return.